# Parquet file format on S3: which is the actual Parquet file?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

Scala 2.12 and Spark 2.2.1 here. I used the following code to write the contents of a `DataFrame` to S3:

```
myDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .parquet("s3n://com.example.mybucket/mydata.parquet")
```

When I go to `com.example.mybucket` on S3 I actually see a **directory** called "*mydata.parquet*", as well as **file** called "*mydata.parquet_$folder$*"!!! If I go into the `mydata.parquet` directory I see two files under it:

- `_SUCCESS`; and
- `part-<big-UUID>.snappy.parquet`

Whereas I was just expecting to see a single file called `mydata.parquet` living in the root of the bucket.

Is something wrong here (if so, what?!?) or is this expected with the Parquet file format? If its expected, which is the *actual* Parquet file that I should read from:

1. `mydata.parquet` directory?; or
2. `mydata.parquet_$folder$` file?; or
3. `mydata.parquet/part-<big-UUID>.snappy.parquet`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mydata.parquet/part-<big-UUID>.snappy.parquet` is the actual parquet data file. However, often tools like Spark break data sets into multiple `part` files, and expect to be pointed to a directory that contains multiple files. The `_SUCCESS` file is a simple flag indicating that the write operation has completed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the api to save the parqueat file it saves inside the folder you provide. Sucess is incidation that the process is completed scuesffuly.

S3 create those $folder if you write directly commit to s3. What happens is it writes to temporory folders and copies to the final destination inside the s3. The reason is there no concept of rename.

Look at the s3-distcp  and also DirectCommiter for performance issue.

Comment: not the direct committer: that can' t handle failure...its why it is missing from spark 2.x

Answer (score 1):

1. The $folder$ marker is used by s3n/amazon's emrfs to indicate "empty directory". ignore.
2. The _SUCCESS file is, as the others note, a 0-byte file. ignore
3. all other .parquet files in the directory are the output; the number you end up with depends on the number of tasks executed on the input

When spark uses a directory (tree) as a source of data, all files beginning with _ or . are ignored; s3n will strip out those $folder$ things too. So if you use the path for a new query, it will only pick up that parquet file.